# Auto-restart process on crash

Tags: unix, java, process, reboot

I have a Java server process which runs native code and the possibility of the entire process crashing due to a problem in native code is always there. Is there any mechanism offered by *nix operating systems wherein I can make the process re-spawn itself when it exists abnormally (exit status != 0)?

Is there any tool/utility out there which can automate this task for any kind of process by providing a certain level of control/configuration at the same time?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a few options - you could always wrap it in a short shell script like this:-

```
#!/bin/sh

RC=1
while [ $RC -ne 0 ]; do
   ./my-java-app
   RC=$?
done
```

Far from elegant, but may suffice.

Comment: Works nice! One more question: is there any tool/utility out there which can automate this task for any kind of process by providing a certain level of control/configuration at the same time?

Comment: Sounds like something I should write :-D

Comment: You really should I guess ;-) BTW, up-voted and accepted.

Comment: You may also want to look at using crontab to monitor your process. This script will also survice a reboot. http://servermonitoringhq.com/blog/how_to_keep_a_job_running_in_linux

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is usually called process monitoring or [process supervision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Supervision). There are many tools that do this, usually as part of a varying set of features. [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) is more and more used for system services in the Linux world. [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is the first thing I'd try for a program not started by root, but there are many alternatives.

Comment: Those tools sounds interesting. For the time being I've decided to go with the simple approach suggested by Andy, but I'll surely keep these tools in mind when it comes to a bit more involved process management. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, just wanted to confirm, given that Monit is GPL'ed tool, would it be OK if it was used for monitoring proprietary apps running on my box?

Comment: @sasuke: The GPL doesn't put any restriction on what you can use the program for. In fact it only comes into play if you *distribute* GPL material.

Comment: Ah, got that. Mucho appreciated. :-)