# kill and restart process by cron

Tags: python, remote, cron, kill

I've got python script running on a remote machine, periodically it stops responding so I ssh in, kill the existing process, and then restart it. I have to do this several times a week and it's causing long periods of downtime when I'm not around. I'd like to restart it every hour by cron - but restarting doesn't work unless I kill the process first.  How would I go about killing the process by cron? Or would there be a more efficient solution.

Comment: The best solution would be to fix whatever is causing the script to hang in the first place.

Comment: Please do some research using `man cron` and `man kill`, you should be able to create a shell script to do what you want. Let us know what part of it doesn't work for you... :)

Comment: **See also:** [Auto-restart process on crash](http://superuser.com/questions/223449/auto-restart-process-on-crash), [Scheduled process killing and restart](http://superuser.com/questions/290901/scheduled-process-killing-and-restart)

Comment: i seem to rememebr there's a thing called supervisor that is designed to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A efficient way is changing your script where it closes all the input stream's, socket's, and such and then open's it again (like a full restart).

But your way is also good here is how you do it: [`man killall`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall)

Comment: Please note that `killall` is not implemented the same everywhere, consult `man killal` before using to avoid the literal kill-all behavior. But indeed, that sugesstion would also work...

Comment: "killall python" is exactly the missing piece of the puzzle - thank you!

Comment: @Joe of course, that will kill ALL python scripts, not just the one you want.  It would be better to record the pid of the script in a file when you launch it, and then kill just that pid later when restarting.

Comment: Oh of course you are right from a best practice point of view, and that's certainly a long-term use.  But to get the thing working killall python was the start I needed.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to enable killing and restarting of your process would be the `killall -9 $name_of_binary` command.

A more sophisticated method is to make a file with the process PID. For instance, it could be started like this:

```
$name_of_binary &
echo $! > $pidfile
```

Then the process can be killed like this:

```
kill -9 $(cat $pidfile) && rm $pidfile
```

You could also incorporate checks that `$pidfile` doesn't exist before starting your process & c.

Comment: grawity: Just because I'm curious, why should there be an LF in the pidfile?